# when app run it crash and the main function is not call

Tags: ios, objective-c

When I run my app on a iOS6 or iOS7 device, it crashes but it doesn't do so on iOS 5.1.1.

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSLog(@"----main----"); // This is not run!
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

And in the simulator it runs ok.

Clean the project and reinstall the application doesn't help.

The log is below:

```
XXXX_test_ios(243) malloc: recording malloc stacks to disk using standard recorder
XXXX_test_ios(243) malloc: stack logs being written into /private/var/mobile/Applications/2E60A0A0-AA10-4CD6-AB74-85901B5D9D53/tmp/stack-logs.243.XXXX_test_ios.index
XXXX_test_ios(243) malloc: Please issue: cp /private/var/mobile/Applications/2E60A0A0-AA10-4CD6-AB74-85901B5D9D53/tmp/stack-logs.243.XXXX_test_ios.i4TU9E.link /tmp/
2014-10-28 10:58:31.529 ktplay_sdk_test_ios[243:907] *** -[CFString release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x1cd78950
```

Can anybody give me some advice what can I do?

Comment: You're over-releasing a string. Check all your allocations and frees and make sure they match up. Using the "Zombies" Instrument in the Instruments app may help you find the string that's being released twice.

Comment: @user1118321 but the main function is not call. It means that all my code has not been called

Comment: The main function has been called - it will often show main() in the debugger as a result of an exception. Set an exception breakpoint in the breakpoint navigator

Comment: Sorry， There are some golbal object in my app and I didn't notice it . Reslove the double release of NSString in global object it runs good.

Answer (score 0):

There are some golbal object in my app and I didn't notice it . Reslove the double release of NSString in global object it runs good.

A lot of this will do before main function calls. such as global variable， static variable. and some system funcion will call (objective-c load function).